# Help understanding the end of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I'm new to number theory and I'm using "Elementary Number Theory" by James K. Strayer. Written below is the ending of the uniqueness part of the FTA proof (done by contradiction) that I'm having trouble understanding:

Now assume, by way of contradiction, that $a_i \neq b_i$ for some i. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a_i < b_i$ Then $$p_i^{bi}|p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_n^{a_n} \qquad (a)$$ which implies that $$p_i^{b_i-a_i}|p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}}p_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}}...p_n^{a_n} \qquad (b)$$ Since $b_i-a_i>0$, we have that $$p_i|p_1^{a^1}p_2^{a_2}...p_{i-1}^{a_{i-1}}p_{i+1}^{a_{i+1}}...p_n^{a_n}$$ from which $p_i|p_j$ for some $j \neq i$, by Corollary 1.15. This is a contradiction. So $a_i=b_i, \quad i=1,2,...,n$. (The proof finishes here)

For reference, Corollary 1.15 states: Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ with p prime. If $p|a_1,a_2,...,a_n$, then $p|a_i$ for some i.

How is it that we can assume $a_i<b_i$? How is (b) implied by (a)? And with (b), how did the "$b_i-a_i$" exponent come about? Up to this point in the book, I don't see a lemma or corollary that helped me understand the end of this proof.

Comment: If two numbers are not equal, then one of them is less than the other. Since the labels are arbitrary (swapping $a$ for $b$ at the start does not change the statement), we can choose one of them to be the smaller and the other to be the larger.

Comment: @SammyBlack This makes sense. So if it were $b_i < a_i$, then it follows that the line after would be $p_i^{a_i}|p_1^{b_1}...p_n^{b_n}$, yes?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3837985/242) more generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the words “assume without loss of generality” mean that if the thing we are about to assume is not true, we can make it true by relabeling the objects in the statement. In this case we would swap the names $a_i$ and $b_i$.
This saves a lot of boring repetition of cases where the only thing that has changed is which variable names have which role.

Between (a) and (b), the numbers on both sides of the “divides” symbol are divided by $p_i^{a_i}$. This relies on the fact that if you have integers $k$, $m$, and $n$ such that $km\mid kn$, then $m\mid n$.

When we divide $p_i^{b_i}$ by $p_i^{a_i}$, the result is

$$
\frac{p_i^{b_i}}{p_i^{a_i}}=p_i^{b_i-a_i}.
$$

I do not have a copy of the book, so I can only guess that these last couple of steps are examples of facts that have already been shown to be true in general.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it clearer.